# i have two sets of data, arranged in two columns. dataM has some points that match w the dataS; how do I find the rows at which they match?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indices

I have two sets of data that describe the quantum properties of a molecule as well as the energy. DataS has 45k points but no uncertainty, DataM has 5k but each energy has an uncertainty. The main goal is to attach the uncertainties we know from DataM into the more comprehensive DataS. Using the other quantum properties, which are compiled into a single column for ease, how can i match up data from dataS to data from dataS so i know which row/position in dataM i can attach an uncertainty to. We're basically using the other quantum properties to identify the correct energy. I dont want a 1-1 function; it should sift through Column M to find which row in Column S matches.

An excerpt of what each column looks like:

```
                      S              M        ΔE
 0         0+X1Sigmag+0   0+X1Sigmag+0  0.000000
 1         0+X1Sigmag+1   2+X1Sigmag+0  0.008930
 2         0+X1Sigmag+2   4+X1Sigmag+0  0.002009
 3         0+X1Sigmag+3   6+X1Sigmag+0  0.001273
 4         0+b3Sigmag-0   8+X1Sigmag+0  0.005600
 5         0+X1Sigmag+4  10+X1Sigmag+0  0.001979
 6         0+b3Sigmag-1  12+X1Sigmag+0  0.001763
 7         0+X1Sigmag+5  14+X1Sigmag+0  0.001962
 8         0+b3Sigmag-2  16+X1Sigmag+0  0.006180
 9         0+X1Sigmag+6       2-a3Piu0  0.004950
 10        0+b3Sigmag-3       3-a3Piu0  0.005230
```

Evidently, the first one matches so I would attach an uncertainty of 0 for row 1 (0 as its Python)

```
 S = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns= ['Properties']).values
 M = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns= ['Properties']).values
```

I have organised into two dataframes and currently been using:

```
 equal_indices = []
 for i in range(len(S)): 
    for j in range(len(M)): 
        if S[i] == M[j] and M[i]==S[j]:
            equal_indices.append(j [have also tried i]) 
            print(i,j)
```

It takes too long and produces nothing useful... the length is an issue as I would be inputting larger datavalues once ive successfully managed this.

I would like to end up with a code that looks like this (the others rows I made up but the first is correct) but for however many matches:

```
ith row    matched property     resultant uncertainty 
0           0+X1Sigmag+0         0.000000
17          0+b3Sigmag-2         0.060789
450         2-a3Piu              0.005230
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
        if S[i] == M[j] and M[i]==S[j]:
```

If S and M have different lengths, it is clearly wrong to index M with i and S with j.

```
        if S[i] == M[j]:
```

Try this instead; if it yields correct results, but is too slow, we can start to optimize.

> how to attach that third column (which corresponds to those j values) over the whole columnS dataset

In order to join the two sets of data, we can forget about the above loops and use (as also krewsayder suggests) [DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
data = data1.merge(data2, 'left', 'Properties')
```

The merge type `'left'` preserves the key order of the *more comprehensive* `data1` set which you didn't want to be reordered.

Comment: okay that does work, and it begins to print out the matching pairs of i and j so cheers but its much too slow, its still printing out results 10 mins later

Comment: i also need to figure out how to attach that third column (which corresponds to those j values) over the whole columnS dataset

Comment: I added how to call `merge` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, welcome to stack overflow.

You can merge the 2 dataframes on the column to get an exact match assuming you want the results where DataS = DataM?

This will return data as if you had done an inner join in SQL, with the left/right keys being denoted by left_on/right_on.

```
DataM.index.name = 'M RowNum'
DataS.index.name = 'S RowNum'
Matched = DataS.reset_index()\
               .merge(DataM.reset_index(), left_on = 'S', right_on = 'M', how = 'inner')
```

If you want the row index from either you can add a method to reset the index such as `DataS.reset_index()` attached to either dataframe.

Comment: i tried this, so it reordered my data numerically which unfortunately wasnt what i was going for. The data in dataS wont (usually) be on the same line as the data in dataM that it matches (i.e. that has an identical datapoiint)

Comment: i tried something similar:                                                                                            result = dataM.loc[dataM['M'].isin(dataS['S'])] which gave around 4700 results but the output had many repeats and gave v little information that i could use (even if there are a few repeats, i couldnt find out the row, only the properties that potentially match w each other)

Comment: Do you need the datapoints to be on the same line?  You can add the axis as a join column.

Comment: truthfully im not too fussed about that, im more focused on the actual corresponding row and then only the matched property

Comment: I made an edit for showing rownumbers.  You mentioned that your data was reordered numerically.  What did you mean by this?  This is an inner join so it will exclude columns, but you can change the join types.  It should not have changed the order.   The edit I made created a column which displays the original index and you can create filters on this if that helps.